# Scope for Accessing Storage Account using Managed Identity

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-storage

I'm using managed identity to access azure database in this manner.The Azure App Registration is used for getting the token and the token is passed to the connection.In the same manner,how do i connect to a storage account and write to a container? What will be the **scope** in this case?

```
            AuthenticationResult authenticationResult = null;
            var _app = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ClientId"))
                  .WithAuthority(string.Format(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AADInstance"), Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("Tenant")))
                  .WithClientSecret(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ClientSecret")).Build();

            authenticationResult =  _app.AcquireTokenForClient(new string[] { "https://database.windows.net/.default" }).ExecuteAsync().Result;           
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("DBConnection")))
            {
                conn.AccessToken = authenticationResult.AccessToken;
                conn.Open();

                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM mytable", conn))
                {
                    var result = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
                    Console.WriteLine(result);
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure Storage uses this scope:

```
https://storage.azure.com/.default
```

That said, with the new [Azure Storage SDK](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Azure.Storage.Blobs/) and [Azure.Identity](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Azure.Identity), you don't actually need to know this.
You can use them like this:

```cs
var credential = new ClientSecretCredential(tenantId: "", clientId: "", clientSecret: "");

var blobUrl = "https://accountname.blob.core.windows.net";
var service = new BlobServiceClient(new Uri(blobUrl), credential);

var container = service.GetBlobContainerClient("container");
var blob = container.GetBlobClient("file.txt");
// TODO: Write the file
```

Comment: For database access you don't need to know the scope too?

Comment: For that at the moment I think you do need to know it :) At least with Entity Framework Core 3.1, we use a connection interceptor class that then acquires tokens for the DB connections. And it has that scope value you used in a constant.

Answer (score 0):

For Azure Storage, the scope will be `https://storage.azure.com/.default`.

Please see this link for more details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-auth-aad-app?tabs=dotnet#azure-storage-resource-id.